# Creating a virtual device

Tags: android, virtual-device-manager

I am trying to create a virtual device on Android Studio. It bring an error on the screen stating that I have to set up Intel (R) Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager. I tried to download the hardware accelerated, but my computer do not support Intel Virtualization Technology.

I tried to disable my hyper-v under programs and features but it did not exist on my HP All-in-One Desktop, I also updated my window 8.1 to window 10. I still cannot download the hardware accelerated.

I just need help with either creating the virtual device without the hardware accelerated, or try to get the hardware accelerated to be install.

Comment: Have you tried using the amd processor rather than the x86(intel) one?

Answer (score 0):

Try using GenyMotion as your emulator instead. I've had no problem using it so far.

https://www.genymotion.com/account/login/
Sign up for a free account and you can download a personal license for free.